# Common reoccurring themes in The Canterbury Tales?

Tags: character-analysis, geoffrey-chaucer, the-canterbury-tales, theme

I'm currently reading *The Canterbury Tales* for school and I'm struggling to find a common reoccurring theme for the tales. More specifically the Wife of Bath and Prioress tales. I thought about writing about oppression since women (Wife of Bath) and Jews (Prioress) were both victimized by society. I'm not sure if this is the best argument I can use in my essay as I have to use 3 tales to support it.

Can you help come up with suggestions and better ideas for reoccurring themes? This is a very complex piece of literature for me and is a huge assignment so I'm trying to get to understand the tales as best as I can.